# Add groovy library in mvn project

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I'm new into Groovy and I'm trying to write a very simple project using Groovy as language. I was able to write a hello world script, deploy an mvn artifact and execute it. 
I'm going beyond that right now and I need to import some external libraries for testing matters but I don't know how to do that.

I would really appreciate if you could give me some tips about this.

Thanks!

Comment: How to do what specifically? Use Maven dependencies only in the test phase?

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify dependencies for the project which have `test` scope, in which case they will not be used in `compile` scope, or you can specify dependencies which are only used in certain scenarios (if, for example, you want to write Groovy tests without requiring the rest of your team to do so).

This sample `pom.xml` has a custom `profile` element which describes dependencies and executions to run only if the current environment user is "andylopresto". This means that if my team doesn't want to use Groovy in their build, I could still write my test classes in Groovy and have them run as part of the standard `mvn test` [phase](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html) on my machine only. In my team members' local machines (or a shared Jenkins instance), the Groovy test files will be ignored (not compiled or run, and the `groovy-all` dependency will not even be downloaded onto the machine).

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>your.package</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<packaging>pom</packaging>
<developers>
    <developer>
        <id>alopresto</id>
        <name>Andy LoPresto</name>
        <email>alopresto@example.com</email>
        <roles>
            <role>developer</role>
            <role>owner</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
    <developer>
        <id>jjava</id>
        <name>Johnny Java</name>
        <email>ihategroovy@example.com</email>
        <roles>
            <role>sticking to older languages</role>
        </roles>
    </developer>
</developers>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
         <!-- This dependency is available to all project code -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This dependency is only available during test phase -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- This dependency is expected to be provided outside of Maven -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <!-- Custom profile for Groovy tests used only on Andy's computer -->
        <id>andyLocalTest</id>
        <activation>
            <property>
                <name>env.USER</name>
                <value>andylopresto</value>
            </property>
        </activation>

        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.1</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.8</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/main/groovy</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-test-source</id>
                            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <sources>
                                    <source>src/test/groovy</source>
                                </sources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <compilerId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</compilerId>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.java</include>
                            <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-compiler</artifactId>
                            <version>2.8.0-01</version>
                        </dependency>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                            <artifactId>groovy-eclipse-batch</artifactId>
                            <version>2.1.5-03</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```